# MS Excel formulas displaying #REF when data is entered in a cell in a certain way?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have various complected formulas pulling data from two pages (used as data entry pages), formatting it in specific ways, and displaying it on another third page (all in the same work book).

This all works fine if you type the data in a cell at a time in the data entry pages but if you "cut and paste" from another spreadsheet, or say "grab a cell" and drag it up a few rows to replace the contents of a destination cell, or if you delete a row the formulas go wrong and display #REF ???

I do not understand this behavior and is there anyway to stop it happening?

Thanks

Comment: Use the indirect function to keep the reference cell constant in your formulas.

Comment: hi wbeard52 can you elaborate on that? as i said i have many complicated formulas so how and where exactly do i use the indirect function and where in a formula string do i use it?

Comment: This is an example of one of my more basic formulas '="<td>"&Data_Entry!A1455&"<br />Tel:&nbsp;"&Data_Entry!B1455&"</td>"'

Comment: If you drag or copy/paste, do you end up with exactly the same cell content as what you type in?  It sounds like cell references are adjusting and no longer pointing to what they are supposed to.

Comment: fixer1234 yes thats exactly whats happening

Comment: if i try the following using INDIRECT I get #ref '="<td>"&(INDIRECT(Data_Entry!A2))&"<br />Tel:&nbsp;"&(INDIRECT(Data_Entry!B2))&"</td>"'

Comment: FYI, people will get a message flag that you posted something for their attention only if you "address" the comment in the format @username.  Otherwise, they will be unaware of your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Example:
Type the number 1 on cell A1
Type `=IF(B2<>"";A1+1;"")` in A2, then copy this to ten cells below A2.
Type a, b, c, d, e f in B2 and below

Now check how the formulas in column A references cells. *(Select one cell, hit F2)*
Grab one of the cells in column B and MOVE it up, one step is enough.

For LibreOffice 4.2.7.2 the reference in the formula (in column A) follows the move.
For Excel i believe the reference is replaced by `#REF` - as Excel detects that this would "overlap" the formula in the cell above.
*Cannot check - No access to Excel.*

Which of these is more correct? That might be a subject for a discussion, not covered here.

Replace the formulas in A2 with `=IF(OFFSET(A2;0;1)<>"";A1+1;"")` (and copy down)
and you will be able to move the contents in column B without having the bad effect.
This is due to the fact that the cells in column B isn't DIRECTLY referenced, but via an offset from column A.

--
To move about DATA that is referenced you may do it with these steps:

1. Cut out the data
2. Paste it with "Paste Special > Values" in an unused location (not referenced by any formulas)
3. Make space for the data if necessary (Select and <kbd>Delete</kbd> values)
4. Repeat steps 1 and 2, to get the data placed correctly

Comment: Also, if you don't want the cell reference to adjust, anchor the row and/or column with $ as appropriate before you copy the formula.